# Why the published app android don't login with Google?

Tags: android

I wrote a app to sign up with Google. The app built in Android Studio works very well. But when I publish it the app stop works the Login with Google. Someone knows why?

I do every everything writed in documentation. The app works when is not publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the SHA you've provided to Google sign-up differs from the one Google Play used to sign your build after publishing. You can find the right value in your Play Console in the *Setup -> App signing* section and paste it into your Google sign-up settings.

Comment: I think you rigth!